# Shaky, noisy and hard to open bi-fold doors

Tags: doors, closet

I have multiple closets with bi-fold doors and they all have the same issue: shaky, noisy and hard to open. It looks like the doors were installed using cheap sliding hardware. The doors are so shaky and noisy that I try to not open them.

I am dreaming of seeing those bi-fold doors opening and closing easily and with no noise. Does anybody have experience with those doors? What hardware should I get to replace the cheap sliding hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Bi-fold doors are just terrible. Even at their best they're often jiggly and awkward. They're such a pain that half of them end up perpetually open.

I'd look at replacing the hardware with a kit from your local store. They'll include track, door lap guides, upper rollers, and bottom pins and brackets.

Another problem is when the carpenter puts the knobs in the wrong place. They're often set right near the hinges. This makes the closing force all wrong, which results in premature wear and deformation of hardware. Ideally, the knobs will be in the center of the inner panel. This allows force to be applied in all necessary directions for both opening and closing action.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth - on our doors I found that taking a Scotch-Brite pad to clean the nylon roller & to break the sharp corner at the top helped a bunch. Then cleaning the vertical surfaces of the track w/ something w/ some lubricating properties like Armor All made it even that much better (guessing WD-40 might work even better, just didn't want to spray inside the house w/ that).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know if it's cheep, poorly installed, misadjusted or just worn out.

- Replacement plastic rollers should be available at any hardware
  store.
- If installation was done with the wrong sort of screw, the rollers
  may catch on screw-heads sticking into the track. That problem may be
  exacerbated by worn-out rollers.
- I've seen doors with huge problems opening because the top or bottom
  pin where it hinges was not in its socket at all (just sort of
  flopping - makes for a lot of sticking and shuddering), or because
  the socket was not where it belonged.

Comment: I've also seen situations where the hinges between the two halves of each door section were installed with too short of screws into cheap wood and became loose causing even more poor door behavior. Another thing I've seen, especially on the door types that are made with 3/4" rails and louvers where the wood around the pin hole at the top split causing a huge p.i.t.a.  When these doors are installed correctly and properly adjusted they can be a dream to operate. Let it swing the other way and you wonder if you would ever want to consider bi-fold doors again!!